# How is size of characters in ascii table

Tags: utf-8, byte, ascii, bit

I was confused and i have questions, the first one is how many bites in chars ASCII table, i have heard that any char from ASCII is 7 or 8 bits but let's take an example, char "1" is 110001 so its size 6 bits, my question is "1" 6 bits or 7 bits or 8 bits ?
If the answer is 8 bit like 00110001, how can we encode 00110001 to utf8 .
thank you .

Comment: 0b110001 and 0b00110001 are the same. They both represent number 49. Here is handy [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) table.

Comment: Yes but how is the reserved size in memory ?

Comment: `char` is 1 byte in `C` and `C++` and it represents ASCII. `C++` support wide chars (`std::wchar_t`) which can be 2 or 4 bytes to represent UTF8.

Comment: if 0b1101 to utf8 is 00001101 how is 0b11111111 in utf8

Comment: 0b11111111 is not an ASCII value. ASCII uses only 7 bit. Look into the table I mentioned before. Btw here is [UTF8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) table. You can compare them side by side and see how ASCII is mapped to UTF8.

Comment: Thank you, now i got that ÿ "0b11111111"  is in utf8 encoding "11000011 10111111", you told me 0b11111111 is not ascii value and i find that "0b11111111" have value 255 which point into ÿ, can you explain to me how 255 and ÿ   ?

Comment: ASCII and EXTENDED ASCII are two different things. Please look at  ASCII table I sent you before.

Comment: For practical purpose, now you can say that an ascii character occupy 8 bits=1bytes. On older time we had 6, 7, 8 bit machines (or with other odd number of bits). Note: also printers and serial protocol could send quick text if they used only 7 bit, so they allowed to send 7bit ascii also on 8-bit machine. ASCII was developed when record like machines were developed (and 8086 was also so), C and databases changed this. So: ASCII specify 128 codes, 33 are special (and mostly program dependent). Character above 127 are special (various encodings).